# ActiveAdmin - How to send an http request to a form submit button via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, forms, activeadmin

I am building an ActiveAdmin form as part of a project that started as a simple html+jquery form. As a non-rubyist I am struggling to understand this framework and how I would create a form that sends data to an external server. So far I have this:

```
form action: "http://localhost:3000/test", method :post do |f|
   f.input :my_field, type: text, name: 'test_field'
   f.input :submit, type: :submit
end
```

However, while this does send the post request, it also navigates to this endpoint. I am looking for a form that simply sends data when the form is submitted.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can do `remote: true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set set `remote: true` to your form builder for ajax:

```
form action: "http://localhost:3000/test", method :post, remote: true do |f|
   f.input :my_field, type: text, name: 'test_field'
   f.input :submit, type: :submit
end
```

In you controller you need a `respond_to` block which in normal rails cases you would be handling some data, and return something for the browser as json data, normally the model, but since in your example there's not model, just some text that we don't know what you want to do with, you can just respond with either json or javascript.

```
def test 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.json { render json: {text: params[:text]}, status: :success
  end
end
```

You probably should read the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) which shows how to do AJAX on rails

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer. I tried this, and the page still redirected -- I am hoping for the request to send but for the page to stay.

Answer (score 0):

How is your controller/route responding to the action? Maybe the handler is making the redirect. Try to respond with a simple alert and see what happens.

With that, watch for the network request too and the response, to see what status code is being returned.

cheers